# CoreData object attributes disappearing on creation of next object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, sugarrecord

I'm creating some default data and saving it in coredata on first launch but during creation something is going wrong and I can't figure out what it is. (Using sugarRecord if that matters)

These are the functions for creation:

Default dataLayout (works fine)

```
func createDefaultDataLayout() {
    guard let db = db else { return }
    do {
        try db.operation { (context, save) throws -> Void in
            let defaultData: TMDataLayout = try! context.create()
            defaultData.id = 999

            let spot1: TMData = (try! context.fetch(FetchRequest<TMData>().filtered(with: "id", equalTo: "1")).first)!
            spot1.spot = 1
            let spot2: TMData = (try! context.fetch(FetchRequest<TMData>().filtered(with: "id", equalTo: "6")).first)!
            spot2.spot = 2
            let spot3: TMData = (try! context.fetch(FetchRequest<TMData>().filtered(with: "id", equalTo: "8")).first)!
            spot3.spot = 3
            let spot4: TMData = (try! context.fetch(FetchRequest<TMData>().filtered(with: "id", equalTo: "19")).first)!
            spot4.spot = 4

            defaultData.data = [spot1, spot2, spot3, spot4]
            save()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error creating default data layout")
    }
}
```

Default activities, using the default dataLayout

```
func createDefaultActivities() {
    guard let db = db else { return }
    let defaultPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", "0")

    do {
        try db.operation { (context, save) throws -> Void in

            let defaultDataLayout = try! context.fetch(FetchRequest<TMDataLayout>().filtered(with: defaultPredicate)).first
            let defaultSettings = try! context.fetch(FetchRequest<TMSettingsLayout>().filtered(with: defaultPredicate)).first

            let chosen: TMActivity = try! context.create()
            chosen.id = 999
            chosen.title = L10n.Activity.running
            chosen.iconName = "running"
            chosen.dataLayout = defaultDataLayout
            chosen.settingsLayout = defaultSettings
            chosen.goal = try! context.fetch(FetchRequest<TMGoal>().filtered(with: "title", equalTo: L10n.Goal.Nothing.title)).first
            chosen.isPartOfWorkout = false
            print(chosen)

            let walking: TMActivity = try! context.create()
            walking.id = 1
            walking.title = L10n.Activity.walking
            walking.iconName = "walking"
            walking.dataLayout = defaultDataLayout
            walking.settingsLayout = defaultSettings
            walking.isPartOfWorkout = false
            print(chosen)

            save()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Something went wrong setting up core data (dataManager)")
    }
}
```

The two prints of "chosen" give something different, the first print the object is correct and has the dataLayout and settingsLayout set, but on the second one they have disappeared. I fetch and set the goal in the same way and that ***does*** stay in the object.

Where is it going wrong?

Goal creation func for comparison

```
func createGoalObjects() {
    guard let db = db else { return }
    do {
        try db.operation { (context, save) throws -> Void in
            let duration: TMGoal = try! context.create()
            duration.id = 1
            duration.title = L10n.Goal.Duration.title
            duration.iconName = "duration"
            duration.amount = 0
            duration.descriptionString = L10n.Goal.Duration.amount(Int(duration.amount))

            let pace: TMGoal = try! context.create()
            pace.id = 2
            pace.title = L10n.Goal.Pace.title
            pace.iconName = "pace"
            pace.amount = 0
            pace.descriptionString = L10n.Goal.Pace.amount(Int(duration.amount))

            let distance: TMGoal = try! context.create()
            distance.id = 3
            distance.title = L10n.Goal.Distance.title
            distance.iconName = "distance"
            distance.amount = 0
            distance.descriptionString = L10n.Goal.Distance.amount(duration.amount)

            let calories: TMGoal = try! context.create()
            calories.id = 4
            calories.title = L10n.Goal.Calories.title
            calories.iconName = "calories"
            calories.amount = 0
            calories.descriptionString = L10n.Goal.Calories.amount(Int(duration.amount))

            let nothing: TMGoal = try! context.create()
            nothing.id = 5
            nothing.title = L10n.Goal.Nothing.title
            nothing.iconName = "nothing"
            nothing.amount = 0
            nothing.descriptionString = L10n.Goal.Nothing.amount

            save()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error creating default data layout")
    }
}
```

Here are the 2 prints I get:

```
<TMActivity: 0x1c40990a0> (entity: TMActivity; id: 0x1c422d2c0 <x-coredata:///TMActivity/tA820CA64-1F5A-480D-A631-0BC3E05FFC9237> ; data: {
    dataLayout = "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://62477925-6CCB-472D-8C45-BD6731B59AA6/TMDataLayout/p1>";
    goal = "0xd0000000000c0006 <x-coredata://62477925-6CCB-472D-8C45-BD6731B59AA6/TMGoal/p3>";
    iconName = running;
    id = 999;
    isPartOfWorkout = 0;
    partId = 0;
    parts =     (
    );
    settingsLayout = "0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://62477925-6CCB-472D-8C45-BD6731B59AA6/TMSettingsLayout/p1>";
    title = Hardlopen;
})
<TMActivity: 0x1c40990a0> (entity: TMActivity; id: 0x1c422d2c0 <x-coredata:///TMActivity/tA820CA64-1F5A-480D-A631-0BC3E05FFC9237> ; data: {
    dataLayout = nil;
    goal = "0xd0000000000c0006 <x-coredata://62477925-6CCB-472D-8C45-BD6731B59AA6/TMGoal/p3>";
    iconName = running;
    id = 999;
    isPartOfWorkout = 0;
    partId = 0;
    parts =     (
    );
    settingsLayout = nil;
    title = Hardlopen;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set my dataLayout and settingsLayout relationship to many, that fixed it

Comment: Please mark your own answer as the answer to question, in this case.

Comment: @Manganese I tried but I can't yet, it says I need to wait 2 days